# Passing value from jsp input textfield to system.out.println

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Basically , i am trying to figure out how can we pass value from input text box to system.out.println without needing a submit button .

For an example. we can achieve this with wrapping a form like ...

```
--- JSP FILE ---

<form action="servlet" method="post">
<input type="text" value="test" name="name"/>
</form>

---- Servlet file ---

String name = request.getParameter("name");
System.out.println(name);
```

By doing , we can get the value inside the println , but a submit button is needed.

But what im trying to achieve is getting the value without the need to have submit button. For an example, if we doing it in javascript way , we can use onchange funtion and inside the body tag.

```
<input type="text" onchange="function ..()">;...
```

But whereelse for java jsp servlet . is it possible to achieve such thing ?

E.g

Inside our jsp file .

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="testing"/>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to console it, with scriptlets you can do something like this, you have to use this in conjunction with javascript to get the value from your input though (changing the jsp file name to your own):

```
<script>
    function call() 
    {
        var name = "Farid";
        window.location.replace("test2.jsp?name=" + name);
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Get" onclick='call()'>
<%
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    if (name != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
%>
```

Comment: But how can we achieve it without using a button. for an example , 
It will automatically capture the name "farid" into console.

Comment: For an example


<input type="text" value="Farid" name="testing" />



<%
String name = request.getParameter("testing");


System.out.println("name " + name); 

%>

Comment: yeah you can just remove the surrounding function from the javascript. But then it will continuously loop, so you need to make it only load once, you can find code for that on another question. But i don't understand why you even want to do this? This is overly complicated for something that doesn't need to be so complex. What gives?